# How to simulate New and existing users load in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter,
When we enable "Clear cookies each iteration?" option then test user will behave like new user on each iteration.
When we disable "Clear cookies each iteration?" option then test user will behave like user who remembers cookies from the website.

Is there any way to simulate load with 60%(New user) and 40%(existing user: no cookies cleared) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is just going for 2 separate Thread Groups, it has `Same user on each iteration` box where you can control the behaviour of the new/returning user:

[image]

If for some reason you need to use a single Thread Group - you can put your request(s) under 2 [Throughput Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and where you need to simulate a new user add a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the first request and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
sampler.getCookieManager().clear()
```

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)